# FR 5311M Programmable servo?

Tags: arduino, motor, raspberry-pi, servo, diy

I bought this odd servo motor called the [FR 5311M](http://www.feetechrc.com/product/continuous-rotation-servo/two-working-mode-digital-programmable-metal-gears-servo-fr5311m/) from FeeTech, which is advertised as a programmable servo motor which can switch from position to continuous rotation by flashing it with FeeTech's [FR 5311M programmer device](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/feetech-frs-servo-programmer.html). I'm wondering if there is any way to use something like an Arduino or Rasberry Pie to flash the motor instead of using FeeTech's programmer?

Comment: http://boteon.com/blogs/labseven/scpc-2-manual-smart-control-servo-scsxx-and-ttlinker.html  
 ....... 
  http://www.allmotion.com/New%20PDF's/sv10/Command_Set_EZSV10.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like an expensive item to buy, yet looks like an expensive item to make just 1.

[image]

Anything may be possible with infinite resources but SCPC-1 protocol sounds like one those million different types that is sufficiently unique to waste a lot of time on.

Comment: I don't think that is the right programmer for the FR 5311M. There is no mention of the SCPC-1 protocol for this motor and the programmer I mentioned also does not use SCPC-1 protocol. This is the motor [link](http://www.feetechrc.com/product/continuous-rotation-servo/two-working-mode-digital-programmable-metal-gears-servo-fr5311m/) and the programmer is [link](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/feetech-frs-servo-programmer.html).

Comment: Same pinout but  who knows, your link is only CAD $6.40

Comment: http://www.feetechrc.com/wp-content/images/SCPC-1-V1.1.pdf

Comment: hmm I guess, I'll use their programmer. Thanks for the advice!